# Can you assign values to Individuals based off of classes instances?

Tags: instance, ontology, protege, protege4

As shown in the screenshot, I have some subclasses of Person, and I've created Instances for Educational Level such as First_Level, Second_Level etc..

I'm wondering how would I assign these to individuals I have created or would I create these subclasses within Data Properties and assign it to individuals that way?[image][image: Instances of sub class]

Thought I would've been able to assign Instances to individuals, but the only options I have are Object and Data property assertions under individuals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign an instance to an individual - instance and individual are synonyms in this context. If you want to establish a relation between two instances (i.e., two individuals), you should use an object property.

That said, your taxonomy looks surprising to me. Why would a date of birth be a subclass of Person? A date is not a kind of person, in most domains. Perhaps those shouldn't be subclasses of Person, and this is why you're finding it difficult to model your assertions?

Comment: This makes sense, so would Employment_History and Place_Of_Birth also not be a type of person I assume?
Just not sure what else I could add as class for my person ontology.

Also, could I assign Employement history and Educational level as a separate class instead?  Just not sure how I would assign these values to individuals.

Comment: Separate classes would be more common. You'd assign values to individuals with object or data properties (e.g., date of birth would be a data property with a literal value)